# jvisualvm hangs when profiling a local process

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

when I use `jVisualVM`, I see two local processes: `VisualVM` itself and the process I am interested in let's call it `ProcessX`. When I doubleClick the `VisualVM` process, everything works fine. When I doubleclick `ProcessX`, the application is stuck and doesn't correspond anymore. I use `eclipse` to run my java application, and I have a stand-alone version of `jVisualVM` on a `Windows x64` box. I run jVisualVM from "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin". [Setting the Proxy to "No Proxy" in the `VisualVM` menu didn't help me either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494095/java-visualvm-hangs-connecting-to-locally-process-launched-from-eclipse)

Comment: Do you have any special JVM parameters for the process to check (ProcessX)?

Comment: No I don't have any special JVM parameters set.

Comment: have this problem too, did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 10):

There can often be a DNS resolution issue if the process you're trying to connect to using VisualVM is running on localhost. If that's the case, try adding the following system property to the process you're trying to connect to:

```
 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6782309/80144 and
[Has anyone ever got a remote JMX JConsole to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work)

Comment: That worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had absolutely the same problem and I hope my solution will help someone else.

The problem and solution: My system is x64, but I ran Intellij Idea file "idea.exe" (this is default exe file. And it's for x32 system) and I ran Java app from IDE. jVisualVM couldn't connect to it, because I installed x64 jdk. When I realize my mistake and run idea64.exe - the problem was resolved. I can open any java process that I run from IDE.

So if you have x64 system - download and run proper version of eclipse.